# When handling a form POST in a Django views.py, it appears to ignore the HttpResponse type

Tags: python, django, csv, httpresponse, forms, http-post

I have a Django application that generates a table of data. I have a form where you enter parameters and click one button to see the results or another to download a CSV. Seeing the results is working, but downloading the CSV is not.

I handle the response in the views.py, set the content type and disposition, and return the response. Rather than downloading the CSV, it displays the data as text. (I tried both StreamingHttpResponse and plain HttpResponse.) The same exact code works when handling a URL passing in the parameters. So, I tried a HttpResponseRedirect instead, and it does nothing. I even tried just redirecting to a plain URL, with no effect. I believe the response type is being ignored, but I don't know why.

html:

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="form" id="form1">
{{ form.days }} {{ form.bgguserid }}
<input type="submit" value="Go!" id="button-blue"/>
<input type="submit" name="csv-button" value="CSV" id="csv-button"/>
</form>
```

views.py attempt 1:

```py
def listgames(request, bgguserid, days=360):
    if 'csv-button' in request.POST:
        # create CSV in variable wb
        response = StreamingHttpResponse(wb, content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="collectionvalue.csv"'
        return response
```

attempt 2, the same but with:

```py
response = HttpResponseRedirect ('/collection/{0}/csv/{1}/'.format(bgguserid,days))
```

I'm open to other solutions like a client-side redirect to the functioning URL, but I don't want to lose the form validation, and my HTML/javascript skills are weak.

Comment: Have you got any JavaScript involved in that form submission?

Comment: Have you tried doing it like the docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/outputting-csv/   (if you're using a `StreamingHttpResponse` the first argument needs to be an iterable of bytestrings).

Comment: There is no javascript on the form.

Comment: The CSV is being generated by a pandas DataFrame's to_csv method, so I'm not writing it line-by-line. Note that the same code works (downloads the CSV) when called directly by URL.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.
The code in views.py (which I partly copied from somewhere) was creating a new HttpRequest object from the return value of the form handling method.

```py
def indexform(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
        form = IndexForm(request.POST)
        # Check if the form is valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            response = listgames(request, bgguserid=form.cleaned_data['bgguserid'], days=form.cleaned_data['days'])
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpRequest(response)
```

By changing that last line to just return response, it works as intended. Sorry for wasting anyone's time.